# Update confirmation email migration

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to change the content of email template `'customer_user_confirmation_email'`.
So i created a AbstractHashEmailMigration like mentionned in  https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/platform/EmailBundle/email-templates-migrations/
But it wont update the changes

```
class GdmEmailTemplate extends AbstractHashEmailMigration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getEmailHashesToUpdate(): array
    {
        return [
            'customer_user_confirmation_email_gdm' => ['c9a6191f197cb5d3c7bf166c6a246e42']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Return path to email templates
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailsDir()
    {
        return $this->container
            ->get('kernel')
            ->locateResource('GDM/Bundle/CustomerUserBundle/Migrations/Data/ORM/data/emails/customer-user');
    }
}
```

I dont know what to add in **Migrations>Data>ORM>Schema>vx_y** to load the changes, i run oro:migration:load and clear cach but nothing happens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Schema migrations* are for changing the database schema
- *Data migrations* (also called data fixtures) are for filling the database with the data.

Email templates changes are not related to **schema migrations**. So there is nothing to do with the Schema>vx_y folder.

See the documentation on working with the [data fixture (or **data migration**)](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities-data-management/data-fixtures/) instead.

To summarize, your Data Migration must be placed to `Migrations/Data/ORM/` folder in a bundle and then executed with the `oro:migration:data:load` command as mentioned in the above documentation.

*P.S. Probably, the name of the abstract class must be changed to `AbstractHashEmailDataFixture` or something else less confusing.*